# Export data from MySQL - replace '0000-00-00'

Tags: mysql

I have a table with multiple date fields.  Some of the date values are '0000-00-00', which are invalid when I try to upload them to Google BigQuery.

I don't want to change the data in the database, I'd rather write a query and then export the results.  I could do it like so:

```
SELECT IF(datefield = '0000-00-00','0001-01-01',datefield) AS datefield FROM mytable
```

However I've have to do this for every date field, and then change the query if any other date field was added in the future.

Is there a better way?

Comment: what date would you update them too? if so why not `update .. where datefield = '0000-00-00'`?

Comment: I don't want to update the database, as I'm not sure of the repercussions

Comment: You can use dynamic sql generation by checking in information_schema which columns are of date data type and generate the sql code on the fly.

Comment: ok, do you use a server-side language like PHP at all? And what would you have the date updated to? just today's date?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs you can see in the question what value the OP would like to show in place of 0000-00-00

Comment: @Shadow where? All I see is a select statement, and the words replace? where is the replace val?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs `'0001-01-01'` is the replace value

Comment: @shadow oh I didn't know ifs worked like that in MYSQL, that's some weird shizzle haha